# Google Admin SDK Reports v1 Activities: watch broken for applicationName groups

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client

When trying to use the Google Admin SDK Reports v1 API to set up watches for groups I've started to get this error:

```
TypeError: Parameter "applicationName" value "groups" is not an allowed value in "[u'access_transparency', u'admin', u'calendar', u'drive', u'gcp', u'gplus', u'group', u'groups_enterprise', u'login', u'mobile', u'rules', u'token', u'user_accounts']"
```

When changing it to `group` i get this error instead:

```
TypeError: Parameter "applicationName" value "group" does not match the pattern "(admin)|(calendar)|(drive)|(login)|(mobile)|(token)|(groups)|(saml)|(chat)|(gplus)|(rules)|(jamboard)|(meet)|(user_accounts)|(access_transparency)|(groups_enterprise)|(gcp)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in the last day or so Google has decided to rename the `applicationName` from `groups` to `group` without any notice(?).

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/watch

And in their Discovery document for the admin reports_v1 API they updated the enum to reflect the changed `applicationName` but their pattern still requires `groups`.

Pattern:

```
"pattern": "(admin)|(calendar)|(drive)|(login)|(mobile)|(token)|(groups)|(saml)|(chat)|(gplus)|(rules)|(jamboard)|(meet)|(user_accounts)|(access_transparency)|(groups_enterprise)|(gcp)",
```

Enum:

```
"enum": [
  "access_transparency",
  "admin",
  "calendar",
  "drive",
  "gcp",
  "gplus",
  "group",
  "groups_enterprise",
  "login",
  "mobile",
  "rules",
  "token",
  "user_accounts"
]
```

This causes an error in basically all Google API Client libraries since they use the Discovery documents to validate API calls when trying to set up watches for groups using the Reports API.

But even if you patch the Google API Client library to ignore the validation it still fails with HTTP 400 because Google also uses the enum and pattern for their own backend validation.

I've created a case with Google Enterprise support regarding this (case #20884138) and I'm waiting for an response.

**EDIT**: it seems they have rolled back the discovery document for the admin reports_v1 API and it now works once again with applicationName=groups

**EDIT #2**: Google said they will update the docs from `group` to `groups`

Comment: ```Parameter "applicationName" value "meet" is not an allowed value in "['APPLICATION_NAME_UNDEFINED', 'ACCESS_TRANSPARENCY', 'ADMIN', 'CALENDAR', 'CHAT', 'DRIVE', 'GCP', 'GPLUS', 'GROUPS', 'GROUPS_ENTERPRISE', 'JAMBOARD', 'LOGIN', 'MEET', 'MOBILE', 'RULES', 'SAML', 'TOKEN', 'USER_ACCOUNTS', 'CONTEXT_AWARE_ACCESS', 'CHROME']"``` is what I am getting despite having the right applicationName.

Comment: @sakib11 what client library are you using? It looks like the one you are using might require the applicationName to be in all caps.

Comment: I tried bothways. it is fairly inconsistent. I am using the python library.

Comment: I opened an issue on github. ```https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/999``` the suggestion seems to be just clearing the tmp files.